# Run exe command for each file (and directory) recursively, including hidden files, in one line

Tags: powershell

Somehow this does not work on hidden files (it has no effect on those files):

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | foreach {attrib.exe -s -h $_.FullName}
```

However this works for all files in a folder:

```
attrib.exe -s -h '.\path\*'
```

Comment: Need a bit more info than that. What is the current state of the files? Are they hidden already? Get-Childitem doesn't see the hidden files unless you tell it to look for it

Comment: Yes they are hidden. :) *fasepalm* for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-Childitem` doesn't see hidden files by default. Add the `-Hidden` switch to see hidden files

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Hidden | Foreach-Object { attrib.exe -s -h $_.FullName }
```

If you want to see all the files, use the -`Force` switch

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | ForEach-Object { attrib.exe -s -h $_.FullName }
```

More info about Get-ChildItem can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1).